Querying number of replicas from application when auto scaling enabled
We have integrated auto-scaling to our kubernetes setup with KEDA. Currently we are using KEDA custom auto scalers as triggers for auto-scaling with our custom logic. We have a component which have specific requirement where it should know the count of its replicas available when component is starting. I need a way to implement this. This should work for both statefulsets and deployments. Please add a comment if you need more information

Replicas are the number of pods created by the StatefulSet controller. To see the ReplicaSet (rs) created by the Deployment, run the command kubectl get rs.
StatefulSets manages the deployment and scaling of a set of Pods, and provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods. you can simply find the StatefulSet you want to scale,run kubectl get statefulsets <stateful-set-name>.
As per the kubernetes document, you can try to use init containers to get the replica count.
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: get-replica-count
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c"]
    args: 
      - |
        REPLICAS=$(kubectl get statefulset example-statefulset -o=jsonpath='{.spec.replicas}')
        echo "REPLICAS=$REPLICAS" > /replica-count.txt
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /config
  containers:
  - name: main-container
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /config
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    emptyDir: {}

By the above yaml manifest, kubectl gets the number of replicas and stores it in an empty directory file and  the main container can then read this file to get the replica count.

This would not work in my case because when keda autoscale, pod count is changing. So I want a way to let my application know available replicas in current setup dynamically.

Can you refer to this document, which may helps to resolve the issue.
